# How do i clear out form fields inside a form onSubmit

Tags: reactjs, user-interface, frontend, software-design

so i have this formData which i want to clear(want to clear the form fields) out when i click on the submit button in the form .

```
const[formData,setFormData] = useState(
      [{name:'',description:'',type:'',required:''}]
    )
```

so in my handleSubmit Function is this the right way to clear it?(below) or is there any other way?

```
setFormData([{name:'',description:'',type:'',required:''}])
```

Answer (score 0):

That's fine, you are doing well but with some refactoring it should be:

```
const initialState = {
  name: '',
  description: '',
  type: '',
  required: ''
};

const [formData, setFormData] = useState(initialState)


// later for resetting

setFormData(initialState)
```

Comment: oh cool thanks @SecretKeeper so in my case the initial state would be 
const initialState = [{name:'',description:'',type:'',required:''}] right?

Comment: yeah right , i declared variables with your needs in answer